# Return all records in one query in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search

I have a database in elastic search and want to get all records on my web site page. I wrote a bean, which connects to the elastic search node, searches records and returns some response. My simple Java code, which does the searching, is:

```
SearchResponse response = getClient().prepareSearch(indexName)
    .setTypes(typeName)              
    .setQuery(queryString("\*:*"))
    .setExplain(true)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

But Elasticsearch set default size to 10 and I have 10 hits in response. There are more than 10 records in my database. If I set size to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` my search becomes very slow and this not what I want.

How can I get all the records in one action in an acceptable amount of time without setting size of response?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Thans for your question

Comment: I have 100 documents. I set Integer.MAX_VALUE as size.Got OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space] also in My Jboss. If I give 1000, then worked fine.

Answer (score 22):

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllDocs() {
        int scrollSize = 1000;
        List<Map<String,Object>> esData = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        SearchResponse response = null;
        int i = 0;
        while (response == null || response.getHits().hits().length != 0) {
            response = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
                    .setTypes(typeName)
                    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                    .setSize(scrollSize)
                    .setFrom(i * scrollSize)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
            for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits()) {
                esData.add(hit.getSource());
            }
            i++;
        }
        return esData;
}
```

Comment: This works, but requires loading the whole list of results in memory, which is unnecessary, and even impossible for very large result sets. A more robust solution is to use iterators: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35729505/2091700

Answer (score 13):

The current highest-ranked answer works, but it requires loading the whole list of results in memory, which can cause memory issues for large result sets, and is in any case unnecessary.

I created a Java class that implements a nice `Iterator` over `SearchHit`s, that allows to iterate through all results. Internally, it handles pagination by issuing queries that include the `from:` field, and it only keeps in memory **one page of results**.

**Usage:**

```
// build your query here -- no need for setFrom(int)
SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
                                            .setTypes(typeName)
                                            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()) 

SearchHitIterator hitIterator = new SearchHitIterator(requestBuilder);
while (hitIterator.hasNext()) {
    SearchHit hit = hitIterator.next();

    // process your hit
}
```

Note that, when creating your `SearchRequestBuilder`, you don't need to call `setFrom(int)`, as this will be done interally by the `SearchHitIterator`. If you want to specify the size of a page (i.e. the number of search hits per page), you can call `setSize(int)`, otherwise ElasticSearch's default value is used.

**SearchHitIterator:**

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;

public class SearchHitIterator implements Iterator<SearchHit> {

    private final SearchRequestBuilder initialRequest;

    private int searchHitCounter;
    private SearchHit[] currentPageResults;
    private int currentResultIndex;

    public SearchHitIterator(SearchRequestBuilder initialRequest) {
        this.initialRequest = initialRequest;
        this.searchHitCounter = 0;
        this.currentResultIndex = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (currentPageResults == null || currentResultIndex + 1 >= currentPageResults.length) {
            SearchRequestBuilder paginatedRequestBuilder = initialRequest.setFrom(searchHitCounter);
            SearchResponse response = paginatedRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
            currentPageResults = response.getHits().getHits();

            if (currentPageResults.length < 1) return false;

            currentResultIndex = -1;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchHit next() {
        if (!hasNext()) return null;

        currentResultIndex++;
        searchHitCounter++;
        return currentPageResults[currentResultIndex];
    }

}
```

In fact, realizing how convenient it is to have such a class, I wonder why ElasticSearch's Java client does not offer something similar.

Comment: If someone else adds or removes a document, do we have a guarantee that we iterate over all documents?

Comment: I think using [scrolls](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html) should be more robust.

Comment: It depends on how you compose your `SearchRequestBuilder`. For instance, if you sort the results by ascending doc ID, and only add docs with a higher doc ID, you will iterate through all results.
This answer was written for ES 1.7, when Scrolls did not exist yet. They may be a better alternative indeed.

Comment: Using "from" also limits to 10.000 results as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35206409/3263204). Scrolls don't have this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could use scrolling API.
The other suggestion of using a searchhit iterator would also work great, but only when you don't want to update those hits.

```
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;

QueryBuilder qb = termQuery("multi", "test");

SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(test)
        .addSort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC)
        .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
        .setQuery(qb)
        .setSize(100).execute().actionGet(); //max of 100 hits will be returned for each scroll
//Scroll until no hits are returned
do {
    for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
        //Handle the hit...
    }

    scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId()).setScroll(new TimeValue(60000)).execute().actionGet();
} while(scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length != 0); // Zero hits mark the end of the scroll and the while loop.
```

Answer (score 3):

It has been long since you asked this question, and I would like to post my answer for future readers.

As mentioned above answers, it is better to load documents with size and start when you have thousands of documents in the index. In my project, the search loads 50 results as default size and starting from zero index, if a user wants to load more data, then the next 50 results will be loaded. Here what I have done in the code:

```
public List<CourseDto> searchAllCourses(int startDocument) {

    final int searchSize = 50;
    final SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("course_index");
    final SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

    if (startDocument != 0) {
        startDocument += searchSize;
    }

    searchSourceBuilder.from(startDocument);
    searchSourceBuilder.size(searchSize);

    // sort the document
    searchSourceBuilder.sort(new FieldSortBuilder("publishedDate").order(SortOrder.ASC));
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

    List<CourseDto> courseList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        final SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        final SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();

        // Do you want to know how many documents (results) are returned? here is you get:
        TotalHits totalHits = hits.getTotalHits();
        long numHits = totalHits.value;

        final SearchHit[] searchHits = hits.getHits();

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
            // convert json object to CourseDto
            courseList.add(mapper.readValue(hit.getSourceAsString(), CourseDto.class));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Cannot search by all mach. " + e);
    }
    return courseList;
}
```

Info:
- Elasticsearch version 7.5.0
- Java High Level REST Client is used as client.

I Hope, this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to trade off the number of returned results vs the time you want the user to wait and the amount of available server memory. If you've indexed 1,000,000 documents, there isn't a realistic way to retrieve all those results in one request. I'm assuming your results are for one user. You'll have to consider how the system will perform under load.

Answer (score 0):

To query all, you should build a CountRequestBuilder to get the total number of records (by CountResponse) then set the number back to size of your seach request.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary focus is on exporting all records you might want to go for a solution which does not require any kind of sorting, as sorting is an expensive operation.
You could use the scan and scroll approach with ElasticsearchCRUD as described [here](http://damienbod.com/2014/11/13/csv-export-using-elasticsearch-and-web-api/).

Answer (score 0):

For version 6.3.2, the following worked:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllDocs(String indexName, String searchType) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException{

    int scrollSize = 1000;
    List<Map<String,Object>> esData = new ArrayList<>();
    SearchResponse response = null;
    int i=0;

    response = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
        .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
        .setTypes(searchType)  // The document types to execute the search against. Defaults to be executed against all types.
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
        .setSize(scrollSize).get(); //max of 100 hits will be returned for each scroll
    //Scroll until no hits are returned
    do {
        for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits().getHits()) {
            ++i;
            System.out.println (i + " " + hit.getId());
            writer.println(i + " " + hit.getId());
        }
        System.out.println(i);

        response = client.prepareSearchScroll(response.getScrollId()).setScroll(new TimeValue(60000)).execute().actionGet();
    } while(response.getHits().getHits().length != 0); // Zero hits mark the end of the scroll and the while loop.
    return esData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchResponse response = restHighLevelClient.search(new SearchRequest("Index_Name"), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();
```

Answer (score -2):

1.set the max size ，e.g: MAX_INT_VALUE;

private static final int MAXSIZE=1000000;

@Override
    public List getAllSaleCityByCity(int cityId) throws Exception {

```
    List<EsSaleCity> list=new ArrayList<EsSaleCity>();

    Client client=EsFactory.getClient();
    SearchResponse response= client.prepareSearch(getIndex(EsSaleCity.class)).setTypes(getType(EsSaleCity.class)).setSize(MAXSIZE)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
                    .must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("cityId", cityId)))).execute().actionGet();

    SearchHits searchHits=response.getHits();

    SearchHit[] hits=searchHits.getHits();
    for(SearchHit hit:hits){
        Map<String, Object> resultMap=hit.getSource();
        EsSaleCity saleCity=setEntity(resultMap, EsSaleCity.class);
        list.add(saleCity);
    }

    return list;

}
```

2.count the ES before you search

```
CountResponse countResponse = client.prepareCount(getIndex(EsSaleCity.class)).setTypes(getType(EsSaleCity.class)).setQuery(queryBuilder).execute().actionGet();
```

int size = (int)countResponse.getCount();//this is you want size;

then you can

```
SearchResponse response= client.prepareSearch(getIndex(EsSaleCity.class)).setTypes(getType(EsSaleCity.class)).setSize(size);
```

Comment: this will explode in the validation phase because MAX_RESULT_WINDOW is set as 10000. you need to set the scroll value in the prepareSearch to avoid the scenario. Perhaps using prepareSearchScroll with the scroll Id from your response object will be a better solution.