# why this "from" params can not work in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

well,as shown in the figure;  these params,'limit','offset',mean 'from'and 'size'in ElasticSearch. I search 730000+ result,when i set 'limit' < 10000,i get the right result,but when i set 'limit' >= 10000,it can't works.I can't figure out why.

['from' < 10000 ,has result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHasJ.png)

['from' == 10000, no result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aasZn.png)

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206409/elasticsearch-2-1-result-window-is-too-large-index-max-result-window

Answer (score 0):

I known,the max_result_window default 10000,the from +size can't over the max_result_window.

*curl -XPUT http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_settings -d ‘{ "index" : { "max_result_window" : 100000000}}*

so this problem be solved.