# Going to random page at once with ES (Elasticsearch)

Tags: php, elasticsearch, yii

In interface we have list of rows [logs] shown by Yii1 CGridView widget. 
DataProvider is ES (ElasticSearch). If user just enters index page, he/she sends request to fetch top 30 results [size = 30, from = 0] with descending order by date and id

```
'sort' => [
    'date' => [
        'order' => 'DESC'
     ],
     'id' => [
        'order' => 'DESC'
     ],
],
'from' => $pageFromPrevious * $this->getSize(),
'size' => $this->getSize()
```

And it's working. 
Now if I click last page buttom [CGridView widget allows/shows that button], ES gives me error

```
Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [26160]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting
```

I understand the error above, and looked for alternatives like `search_after` and `scan-scroll`, but they seem not suitable for me. If a user click random page, or edit url [page number] or go to the last page at once? 
What are the correct ways to solve this problem. 
Any advice?

== EDITED ==
P.S: ES v.6.2

== EDITED ==

It's duplicate in case of message "

> ...from + size must be less than or equal to...

"

But I wanted to find answer (

> I understand the error above, and looked for alternatives like
>   search_after and scan-scroll, but they seem not suitable for me

)

to "

> How to solve problem, when user chooses to go to last page at once or
>   at middle of thousandth page

"

And Adam T's answer about "google" seems to be correct.

Comment: You have to check total rows existing before generate pagination , if not you will tryi to get results over quantity data available  . You have the total given by elasticsearch in response

Comment: @Fky yeah, I'm doing that. But it's not a problem, I mentioned above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: \[10000\] but was \[100000\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677198/result-window-is-too-large-from-size-must-be-less-than-or-equal-to-10000-b)

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient memory, a simple option is to increase the index setting `index.max_result_window` from 10000 to the number you require (in this case around 27000).

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings

However, this will not scale indefinitely - you'll run out of memory if you set it too big. It might be worth looking at alternatives to jumping to the last page. For example, changing the sort order in your example to 'ASC' would effectively give you the last page without having to page through all the others first.

Comment: 27000 rows is test db data, prod server's data has much more of that, and it's not the solution to increase value to limit to another number. Changing to ASC is crutch solution. What if a user chooses to go to the middle of multi-million records?

Comment: Then it will require lots of memory or processing time. This is why Google only lets you jump to page 10 in a search result.