# Problem of size for my query to ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I make a request to my ES in Python but I can only get 10,000 data. I will need to recover many more ( several hundred thousand).

I've modified the "size" variable but it can't go over 10.000

```
res_cpe = es.search(index=cpe_index, doc_type="entries", body = {
'size' : 10000,
'query': {
    'match_all' : {}
}
})
```

I would like to have all entries in my "res_cpe" variable

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245841/2396392

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend to increate max window size since this approach isn’t scalable enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use Scroll API which should help you to retrieve large numbers of results (or even all results, like in your case).

This functionality is similar to cursors from a traditional databases.

All you need to do, is to add scroll param to your request in Python client. Minimum viable example could look like this:

```
page = es.search(

index = 'yourIndex',

doc_type = 'yourType',

scroll = '2m',

search_type = 'query_then_fetch',

size = 1000,

body = {

//Your query's body

})

sid = page['_scroll_id']

scroll_size = page['hits']['total']

//Start scrolling

while (scroll_size > 0):

print "Scrolling..."

page = es.scroll(scroll_id = sid, scroll = '2m')

//Update the scroll ID

sid = page['_scroll_id']

//Get the number of results that we returned in the last scroll

scroll_size = len(page['hits']['hits'])

print "scroll size: " + str(scroll_size)

//Do something with the obtained page
```

Example taken from here - https://gist.github.com/drorata/146ce50807d16fd4a6aa

Python client docs reference - https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However when I try iti get the following error : `code` raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'No search type for [scan]')
`code` Any idea ?

Comment: @AlexAngers i will take a look at this

Comment: @AlexAngers updated, search_type sholud be the other value - i will update answer