# Why is the returned result of the Elasticsearch response still caped at 10000 when the parameter max_result_window has been changed?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a Django application with Elasticsearch. I have an index *search_index* where I need to render more than 10 000 results. I manually changed the parameter `max_result_window` to generate more than the 10 000 initial limits But after changing the parameter `max_result_window` and the `size` in the `body_search` of my request, the result keeps being limited to 10 000.

First, I have changed the parameter `max_result_window` to **12345** of the *search_index*, by using the method from the page [Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [100000]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677198/result-window-is-too-large-from-size-must-be-less-than-or-equal-to-10000-b). I checked on http://localhost:9200/*search_index*/_settings, and I have the following result `"max_result_window":"`**`12345`**`"`. Then I changed the parameter `size` of my `body_search = {'query': {...}, 'size':` **`12345`**`}`. But the final result is always limited to 10 000.

Does anyone know why the change is not taken into account in my search ?

Comment: if you can share your query I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I am 99% sure you would be better off using the scroll api / pagination.

But to solve you issue you need to tell elastic to [track the exact score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits)

It can be done via `"track_total_hits": true` in your query.

Comment: Hello Paulo, thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion, but it works if I put the max_result_window value in the track_total_hits key. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It took me almost 2 hours of searching various answers and results.

Add `rest_total_hits_as_int=true` to your query and the 'hits' value will carry the total, like it did with elasticsearch versions prior to 7.

Most answers advice to change max_result_window but this will only affect the actual data you can retrieve with your query, not the actual hits your query has targeted.