# Scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using Elastic Search data format plugin and my requirement is to request a large data set nearly 1 million records. But whenever I request above 10 000 I get the error as below:

> Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to:
>   [10000] but was [100000]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way
>   to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the
>   [index.max_result_window] index level setting."

I tried to change my default page allocation as:

```
http://1.2.3.4:9200/index/_settings -d '{ "index" : { "max_result_window" : 1000000}}'
```

But things are not working for me. Is there is any other alternate?

I am using Elastic Search 5.4 
Data Format plugin as Master

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch 2.1: Result window is too large (index.max\_result\_window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206409/elasticsearch-2-1-result-window-is-too-large-index-max-result-window)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the error message, using scroll api is the efficient way to retrieve large data sets. For example,

```
POST <host_name>:<port_num>/<index_name>/_search?scroll=1m&size=100000
```

As shown above, the size is mentioned as 100000 and scroll is 1m, this means that the scroll api will retrieve 100000 records per hit and this scroll is available for 1 minute. Also, this api returns a scroll id, which should be used for further retrieval of records. Please find the sample below:

```
POST <host_name>:<port_num>/_search?scroll=1m&scroll_id=<scroll_id>
```

Note : Further further scroll api calls, index name need not be mentioned. Only the scroll_id and scroll time is sufficient.

For more information, please refer to the elastic search documentation on scroll api : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html